# C# QuickBooks Cannot add Check

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I'm attempting to add the ability to transfer commission payments from my system to QuickBooks using C#, and I've got a whole bunch of it working except for the add check requests. Currently, I'm getting this output

> CheckAdd
>
> ExpenseLineAddList:
>
> element(2) - Required object is empty
>
> End of ExpenseLineAddList
>
> End of CheckAdd

and here's the code. It's a little long unfortunately, but that's just what surrounds the necessary bits.

```
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection CheckConn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
            MySqlCommand CheckCmd = new MySqlCommand();
            CheckConn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
            CheckConn.Open();
            CheckCmd.Connection = CheckConn;
            CheckCmd.CommandText = "select `companies`.`ParentCompanyName`, `DateTimeStart`, `DateTimeEnd` from `commissiontransfers` join `orders` using (`InvoiceID`) join `companies` using (`CompanyID`) where `Transfered`=0 group by `ParentCompanyName`;";

            MySqlDataReader CheckReader = CheckCmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable Checks;
            using (CheckReader)
            {
                Checks = new System.Data.DataTable();
                Checks.Load(CheckReader);
            }
            CheckReader.Close();
            CheckReader.Dispose();
            CheckConn.Close();
            CheckConn.Dispose();

            foreach (DataRow Check in Checks.Rows)
            {

                IMsgSetRequest AddCheckMsgSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 8, 0);
                AddCheckMsgSet.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue;
                ICheckAdd CheckAddRq = AddCheckMsgSet.AppendCheckAddRq();

                CheckAddRq.AccountRef.FullName.SetValue("Bank Account");
                CheckAddRq.PayeeEntityRef.FullName.SetValue(Convert.ToString(Check["ParentCompanyName"]));
                CheckAddRq.Memo.SetValue("Date Range: From " + Convert.ToDateTime(Check["DateTimeStart"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " to " + Convert.ToDateTime(Check["DateTimeEnd"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
                CheckAddRq.IsToBePrinted.SetValue(true);


                MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection CommissionTransferConn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
                MySqlCommand CommissionTransferCmd = new MySqlCommand();
                CommissionTransferConn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
                CommissionTransferConn.Open();
                CommissionTransferCmd.Connection = CommissionTransferConn;
                CommissionTransferCmd.CommandText = "select `CommissionTransferID`, round(`OrderCommission`-`FactoryCommission`-`ShippingCommission`, 2) `Total`, `orders`.`DateTimePaid`, `companies`.`OldQBName`, `orders`.`Customer` from `commissiontransfers` join `orders` using (`InvoiceID`) join `companies` using (`CompanyID`) where `Transfered`=0;";

                MySqlDataReader CommissionTransferReader = CommissionTransferCmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable CommissionTransfers;
                using (CommissionTransferReader)
                {
                    CommissionTransfers = new System.Data.DataTable();
                    CommissionTransfers.Load(CommissionTransferReader);
                }
                CommissionTransferReader.Close();
                CommissionTransferReader.Dispose();
                CommissionTransferConn.Close();
                CommissionTransferConn.Dispose();

                foreach (DataRow CommissionTransfer in CommissionTransfers.Rows)
                {
                    
                    IExpenseLineAdd ExpenseLineAdd = CheckAddRq.ExpenseLineAddList.Append();
                    ExpenseLineAdd = CheckAddRq.ExpenseLineAddList.Append();
                    ExpenseLineAdd.AccountRef.FullName.SetValue("Contract Labor:1099's");
                    ExpenseLineAdd.Amount.SetValue(Convert.ToDouble(CommissionTransfer["Total"]));
                    ExpenseLineAdd.Memo.SetValue(Convert.ToString(CommissionTransfer["Customer"]) + " - " + Convert.ToDateTime(CommissionTransfer["DateTimePaid"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
                    ExpenseLineAdd.ClassRef.FullName.SetValue(Convert.ToString(CommissionTransfer["OldQBName"]));

                    GetFirstRow("update `commissiontransfers` set `Transfered`=1 where `CommissionTransferID`='" + CommissionTransfer["CommissionTransferID"] + "';");
                }
                CheckAddRq.IncludeRetElementList.Add("TxnID");

                try { 
                    IMsgSetResponse CheckResponseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(AddCheckMsgSet);
                    IResponse CheckResponse = CheckResponseMsgSet.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
                    MessageBox.Show(CheckResponse.StatusCode + ": " + CheckResponse.StatusMessage);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
                }
```

It seems to be acting like my `AddCheckMsgSet` variable is empty, but I can't for the life of me figure out why it would be. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, I spend three hours stuck on this problem, and then solve it myself right after I post it here. Well, the problem had to do with these lines

```
IExpenseLineAdd ExpenseLineAdd = CheckAddRq.ExpenseLineAddList.Append();
ExpenseLineAdd = CheckAddRq.ExpenseLineAddList.Append();
```

All I needed to do was get rid of the second line, since I was already appending a new expense line, and the second append caused the first request to be blank. Hope this helps someone in the future, since I've had only problems with trying to connect to QuickBooks.